# Fail to profile remote java app using TPTP

Tags: java, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I am trying to profile CPU usage using TPTP.
Application to profile run on Linux RH AS5. I installed and configured Agent Controller like described [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/platform/org.eclipse.tptp.platform.agentcontroller/src-native-new/packaging_md/linux/getting_started.html?root=TPTP_Project&view=co#serverlog)

I ran the java application using the command

```
java '-agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=standalone,file=log.trcxml;CGProf' MyApp
```

The monitoring station is All-In-one TPTP version 4.6.2. I followed the stepes described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html)

on Eclipse - on the "Profile Configuration" I choose a new configuration for "Attach to Agent", set the host to my remote linux machine where MyApp is running, test connection succeed and when I get to the **"Agents" tab**, I see "**Pending...**", a background process "**Feching children for host**" is running and can't find anything which makes it impossible to profile.

Any idea?

Comment: I have the sample problem except my remote application is running in a Websphere AppServer. The test connection button works fine but no agents are there... I have set the "-agentlib" variables in the debug parameter field of Websphere and the server is running in debug mode.

Did you find any solution yet? Would be great if there are some people who know more about this topic...

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the Agent Controller on the java application in server mode. Currently your command runs it 'headless' and writes it to a log file.  The website you linked has a list of the various options for the server parameter.

```
java '-agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=enabled;CGProf' MyApp
```